# What are the stripe charges applied to a managed account?

Tags: php, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

I have platform with many managed accounts (engineers) who uses our service to get clients (end user) with the project. We are charging a commission from each  engineer's project amount. (Something like freelancer)

I need to make sure that the engineers will get full amount without any stripe amount imposed on them. All those charges must be charged from our platform account not from any of managed accounts. If they are charging from managed account I need to reduce those charges from our platform commission (`applicatoin_fee` parameter in charge) so that they would have full payment.

Please explain me, How can I find these charges ?

I am confused with this [explanation](https://support.stripe.com/questions/what-is-the-connect-fee-for-managed-accounts) in stripe support.

Our platform is running in France.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> All those charges must be charged from our platform account not from
>   any of managed accounts.

If you charge through the platform, the fees are charged to the platform so your connected accounts wouldn't pay them. From https://stripe.com/docs/connect/payments-fees#charging-through-the-platform:

> When you use the destination parameter...
>   The Stripe fee comes out of the charge object on the platform’s account (i.e., you pay the fee).

If you omit the `application_fee` parameter, the connected account will receive the entirity of the charge minus the Stripe fees. You won't be able to cover all the fees yourself at a loss, but you could certainly calculate the Stripe fees and add them to the total price that the customer pays:
https://support.stripe.com/questions/how-can-i-pass-stripe-s-fees-on-to-my-customer